# Subsetting defined group out of DNAStringSet

Tags: r, match, subset

I want to retrieve a couple of sequences from my `DNAStringSet`. So far I only manage to get a single sequence.

For example: 
A DNAStringset and the list/pattern of sequences I want to isolate.

Testset:

```
aDNAStringSet <- DNAStringSet(c("GCATCCATTAC", "AATCGCCATCC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC"))
```

Names:

```
names(aDNAStringSet) <- c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5")
```

The list of sequences to isolate:

```
patterns <- c("seq2", "seq4", "seq5")
```

What I tested so far:

```
selection <- aDNAStringSet [grep("seq2",names(aDNAStringSet ))]
```

or

```
selection <- aDNAStringSet [grep(patterns,names(aDNAStringSet ))]
```

`grep` works, but only for a single sequence.

----------------------`sapply`and `match` doesn't work: -------

Using `sapply`:

```
selection <- aDNAStringSet[unlist(sapply(patterns, grep, aDNAStringSet$names)), ]
```

or using `match`:

```
selection <-match(c("seq2", "seq4", "seq5"), aDNAStringSet$names)
```

I want a stringset only containing "seq2", "seq4", "seq5", any idea?
Thx
K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
aDNAStringSet[names(aDNAStringSet) %in% patterns]
#  A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
#    width seq                                               names
#[1]    11 AATCGCCATCC                                       seq2
#[2]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq4
#[3]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq5
```

Or using `match`

```
aDNAStringSet[sapply(patterns, function(x) match(x, names(aDNAStringSet)))]
#  A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
#    width seq                                               names
#[1]    11 AATCGCCATCC                                       seq2
#[2]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq4
#[3]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq5
```

Or if you prefer `grep` (for regexp matching)

```
aDNAStringSet[sapply(patterns, function(x) grep(x, names(aDNAStringSet)))]
#  A DNAStringSet instance of length 3
#    width seq                                               names
#[1]    11 AATCGCCATCC                                       seq2
#[2]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq4
#[3]    11 GCATACCTTAC                                       seq5
```

Comment: Thx! I was testing so many different lines,... but didn't hit the right one. Thanks for your help, it works like a breeze.

Comment: along my old question, how to do it for a list? If the `aDNAStrinSet`is a list and I would like to get a new `list` including only the sequences defined by `patterns` ? Something like `smalllist<-biglist[grep("element 1", names(biglist))]` let me select for the elements, but how can I make a new list on the names of the sequences within a list element. For example `smalllist<-lapply(biglist, function(y) y[y %in% pattern])` give a Error: `Error in .Call2("new_XStringSet_from_CHARACTER", ans_class, ans_elementType,  : 
  key 56 (char '8') not in lookup table` any Idea?