# Subsetting list of DNAStringset in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

Along my old question [Subsetting defined group out of DNAStringSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306155/subsetting-defined-group-out-of-dnastringset), I have trouble doing the same for a list.
All my attempts leading to the Error:

`Error in .Call2("new_XStringSet_from_CHARACTER", ans_class, ans_elementType, : key 56 (char '8') not in lookup table`

Working example: 

`library("DECIPHER")
library("Biostrings")`

List of DNAStringsets called `Biglist` and a selection called `patterns` I would like to call to get a new list:

```
  aDNAStringSet <- DNAStringSet(c("GCATCCATTAC", "AATCGCCATCC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC"))
  names(aDNAStringSet) <- c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5") 

  bDNAStringSet <- DNAStringSet(c("GCATCCATTAC", "AATCGCCATCC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC"))
  names(bDNAStringSet) <- c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5") 

  cDNAStringSet <- DNAStringSet(c("GCATCCATTAC", "AATCGCCATCC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC"))
  names(cDNAStringSet) <- c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5") 

  dDNAStringSet <- DNAStringSet(c("GCATCCATTAC", "AATCGCCATCC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC", "GCATACCTTAC"))
  names(dDNAStringSet) <- c("seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5") 



  Biglist<-list(A=aDNAStringSet, B=bDNAStringSet, C=cDNAStringSet, D=dDNAStringSet) 

  patterns <- c("seq2", "seq4", "seq5")
```

Using `grep` I´m able to isolate the `elements`, but that´s not what I want:

```
  newlist<-Biglist[grep("A", names(Biglist))]
```

Using `lapply` should be the right way, but this line leads to an Error:

```
  newlist<-lapply(Biglist, function(y) y[y %in% patterns])
```

`Error in .Call2("new_XStringSet_from_CHARACTER", ans_class, ans_elementType,  : key 101 (char 'e') not in lookup table`

I also don´t understand the Error massage. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Seems you're using an external package, could you add it to your post?

Comment: sure, just added it to the post, its `DECIPHER` and `Biostrings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with an S4 class, therefore, you need a different subset method, in this case, it's `@`

```
#To use `DNAStringSet` function install Biostrings using the following
#source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
#biocLite(c("Biostrings"))
#library(Biostrings)

lapply(Biglist, function(x) x[x@ranges@NAMES %in% patterns])
```